# how to update values for spinner when activity is open?

Tags: android

I have a problem with spinner in my app.It updated when i select value but Problem is that when i close and open activity it shows only first value of my list.can anyone give suggestion for this problem.

```
public class OtherSettings extends Activity {
Spinner spin1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.historysetting);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();



}
public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timespinner);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("5 Minutes");
    list.add("10 Minutes");
    list.add("20 Minutes");
    list.add("30 Minutes");
    list.add("40 Minutes");
    list.add("1 hour");
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

historysetting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Switch
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Location history"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/historytime"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="historytime"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/timespinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code..have you string the selected item?

Comment: post code.................

Answer (score 0):

Move `addItemsOnSpinner2();` to `onStart()` and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on `dataAdapter` after setAdapter.

Comment: it doesn't display any method like    notifyDatasetChanged() after setAdapter.

Comment: Show your xml for historysetting and your declaration of spin1.

Comment: i have added xml and declaration for my question.plz refer

Comment: I found  solution to my problem by using shared preferences